# How could I parse an output command with shell scripting?

Tags: git, bash, shell, whiptail

I'm working on a shell script that is an interface for Git using Whiptail (shell interface).

There is my problem, I would like to create a menu where we could select the branch of a Git repository and return this string to the script.

I know how to get the different names of Git branches with:

```
git branch
```

but I don't know how to parse them to communicate them to Whiptail.

I would like to count the number of branches and communicate as options each branch, one by one.

For example:

```
$> git branch
master
asm
release
debug
```

and I would like in the shell script to use Whiptail as:

```
                                                     Here the number of branch
                                                                    v
whiptail --tittle "Branch select" --menu "Choose your branch" 20 60 4 \
"1" "master" \
"2" "asm" \ 
"3" "release" \
"4" "debug"
```

but I don't know how to parse the output of `git branch` to get this as a shell script, could I get help please?

<sub>Edit: I finally did it :) [Source code](https://github.com/Liroo/ui_linux_git/blob/master/build.sh#L41-L62)</sub>

Comment: I assume the number of branch could be replaced by git branch | wc -l but dunno how to parse and add to the whiptail the branch

Comment: You could post your solution as an answer, or at least the crucial parts for how to get the output into a Whiptail menu.

Comment: There was a link on the last sentence but I modified it to make it more understandable

Comment: Sure, but a link is not really considered an answer here. But no worries, just a suggestion.

Comment: I updated the link with hightlighted lines ! Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: My suggestion was that you would put that here, as an answer ;)

Comment: Yes, i understand, by there is some probleme in the script, i will resolve them before ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what `whiptail` is, but a while ago I wrote a bash function to list all the recent branches you've visited and give the user a menu to pick one.

The [source is in my `.bashrc` on Github](https://github.com/DelvarWorld/configs/blob/master/.bashrc#L54-L116) which I've copied here:

```
# Colors for prompt
COLOR_RED=$(tput sgr0 && tput setaf 1)
COLOR_GREEN=$(tput sgr0 && tput setaf 2)
COLOR_YELLOW=$(tput sgr0 && tput setaf 3)
COLOR_DARK_BLUE=$(tput sgr0 && tput setaf 4)
COLOR_BLUE=$(tput sgr0 && tput setaf 6)
COLOR_PURPLE=$(tput sgr0 && tput setaf 5)
COLOR_PINK=$(tput sgr0 && tput bold && tput setaf 5)
COLOR_LIGHT_GREEN=$(tput sgr0 && tput bold && tput setaf 2)
COLOR_LIGHT_RED=$(tput sgr0 && tput bold && tput setaf 1)
COLOR_LIGHT_CYAN=$(tput sgr0 && tput bold && tput setaf 6)
COLOR_RESET=$(tput sgr0)

# git
function _c() {
    cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    branches=`git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/heads/ | head -n 10`

    output=''
    for branch in $branches
    do
        output+=`echo "$branch" | sed 's/.*refs\/heads\///'`
        # creative way to get color here? echo messes everything up
        # (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107417/what-are-the-special-characters-to-print-from-a-script-to-move-the-cursor ?)
        #output+=" '`git show --quiet $(echo $branch | cut -d' ' -f1) --pretty=format:"%C(Yellow)%h %Cred<%an>%Creset %s %C(cyan)(%cr)%Creset'"`"$'\n'
        #echo " \'`git show --quiet $(echo $branch | cut -d' ' -f1) --pretty=format:"%C(Yellow)%h %Cred<%an>%Creset %s %C(cyan)(%cr)%Creset\'"`"$'\n'
        output+=" \'`git show --quiet $(echo $branch | cut -d' ' -f1) --pretty=format:"%h <%an> %s (%cr)\'"`"$'\n'
    done

    response=''
    for branch in $output
    do
        lowerBranch=`echo $branch | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
        if [[ $branch =~ .*$cur.* ]]; then
            response+=$branch$'\n'
        fi
    done

    COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$response" -- $cur ) )
}

function c() {
    newBranch=""
    inputted=""

    if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
        branchOutput=`git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/heads/ | head -n 10`

        declare -a branches
        let xx=0

        IFS=$'\n'
        pad=$(printf '%0.1s' " "{1..32})
        padlength=32
        for branch in $branchOutput
        do
            # Show them in a list with a counter
            xx=`expr $xx + 1`
            branches=("${branches[@]}" "$branch")
            branchName=`echo "$branch" | sed 's/.*refs\/heads\///'`
            string1="$COLOR_PURPLE$xx. $COLOR_PINK $branchName"
            uncolor="$xx.  $branchName"
            printf '%s' $string1
            printf '%*.*s' 0 $((padlength - ${#uncolor} )) "$pad"
            printf '%s\n' `git show --quiet $branchName --pretty=format:"%C(Yellow)%h %Cred<%an>%Creset %s %C(cyan)(%cr)%Creset"`
        done

        # Prompt user for file. -n means no line break after echo
        echo -n "$COLOR_YELLOW?$COLOR_RESET "
        read branchNumber

        let "branchNumber+=-1"

        if [[ "$branchNumber" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
            newBranch=`echo "${branches[@]:$branchNumber:1}" | sed 's/.*refs\/heads\///'`

            if [[ -z "$newBranch" ]]; then
                echo "Not real."
                return 1
            fi
        else
            echo "Wtf?"
            return 1
        fi
    else
        inputted=1
        newBranch=`echo "$1" | cut -d' ' -f1`
    fi

    if [[ -n "$1" ]]; then
        echo `git show --quiet "$newBranch" --pretty=format:"%C(Yellow)%h %Cred<%an>%Creset %s %C(cyan)(%cr)%Creset"`
    fi

    if [[ $newBranch =~ ^pr ]]; then
        echo -e "\ngit fetch $newBranch && git checkout $newBranch"
        git fetch $newBranch && git checkout $newBranch
    else
        echo -e "\ngit checkout $newBranch"
        git checkout $newBranch
    fi

}

# add autocompletion to the c command
complete -F _c  c
```

If you put this in your `~/.bashrc` and run `source ~/.bashrc` at the command line (or open a new shell) you can then just run the command `c` in your git repo, and you'll get output like this:

[image: what it does]

Or you can simply type `c`<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> to auto-complete branch names:

[image: what it does more]

This took many days to accomplish and I would not wish this process on anyone. Scripting bash to make reasonable UIs is cumbersome.

Comment: https://github.com/Liroo/ui_linux_git/blob/master/build.sh It's cool, i finally did it, i still need to add much features